# What is the formula for sum of $(n-r+1)C_r$ for a given $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I wish to calculate the sum of
$$(n-r+1)C_r$$
for a given $n$.

**Example:** For $n=6$, the sum equals $6C_1 + 5C_2 + 4C_3$.

I have a very large $n$ $(n\ge 10^6)$.

Help please.

Comment: What is $C_{r}$ ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s well known that

$$F_n=\sum_k\binom{n-k-1}k\;,$$

where $F_n$ is the $n$-th [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Use_in_mathematics). Your example actually omits one term, the $k=0$ term; if that’s your intent, then you need to subtract $1$ from this.

There are closed form expressions for $F_n$; probably the most convenient for computation is

$$F_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;,$$

where

$$\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\;.$$

Comment: Sorry I'm not that good at mathematics. Its not getting me the desired answer. For example, n=6, sum=6C1 + 5C2 + 4C3=6+10+4=20.. phi=1.618.. F6=greatest.integer.function((1.618)^n/2.236 + 0.5)=8-1=7.. I need to stop summation when r starts exceeding (n-r+1).

Comment: @Pranjal: You’re using the wrong value of $n$. If you were starting at $k=0$, as in the formula that I gave, your first term would be $\binom70$, so $n-1$ would be $7$, and $n$ would be $8$. Thus, you expect to get $F_8-1$, and $\varphi^8/\sqrt4\approx21.00951949425$. In general, if you’re starting with $\binom{m}1$, you want to take $n=m+2$.

Comment: Error Spotted. :) Thanks a lot Brian.

Comment: @Pranjal: You’re very welcome.